# How do i get the URL of a editable form response in spreadsheets

Tags: url, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

Im trying to get the url of a editable google form response to show up in google sheets,but it does not seem to be working.

I have seen [Awesome Table](https://support.awesome-table.com/hc/en-us/articles/115001156125) and [Ruben's example](https://gist.github.com/rubenrivera/4ed2110cda3fbdbc29d2d2d3a4af29c0). Based of these 2 links and some others, they seem to be working for single form response sheets,but not multiple.

I tried this code 1st:

```
var formURL = 'https://docs.google.com/forms/d/__Your ID__/viewform';
var sheetName = '__Response sheet__';
var columnIndex = __column where it appears__;

function getEditResponseUrls() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var form = FormApp.openByUrl(formURL);
  for(var i = 2; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i][0] != '' && data[i][columnIndex-1] == '') {
      var timestamp = data[i][0];
      var formSubmitted = form.getResponses(timestamp);
      if (formSubmitted.length < 1) continue;
      var editResponseUrl = formSubmitted[0].getEditResponseUrl();
      sheet.getRange(i+1, columnIndex).setValue(editResponseUrl);
    }
  }
}
```

2nd is:

```
// Form URL
var formID = '__Your ID__';
// Sheet name used as destination of the form responses
var sheetName = '__Response sheet__'';
/*
 * Name of the column to be used to hold the response edit URLs 
 * It should match exactly the header of the related column, 
 * otherwise it will do nothing.
 */
var columnName = '__name of column where it appears__' ;

// Responses starting row
var startRow = 2;

function getEditResponseUrls(){
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
    var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues(); 
    var columnIndex = headers[0].indexOf(columnName);
    var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

    var form = FormApp.openById(formId);

    for(var i = startRow-1; i < data.length; i++) {
        if(data[i][0] && !data[i][columnIndex]) {

            var timestamp = data[i][0];
            var formSubmitted = form.getResponses(timestamp);
            if(formSubmitted.length < 1) continue;

            var editResponseUrl = formSubmitted[0].getEditResponseUrl();
            sheet.getRange(i+1, columnIndex+1).setValue(editResponseUrl);
        }
    }
}
```

Nothing is showing up, and when i check the logs for triggers, it is all working fine, no failures.I have tried putting the global variables within the function, but no changes.

Comment: Your version#2 looks like a variation on an answer by @Rubén in webapps [Show URL used to edit responses from a Google Form in a Google Spreadsheet by using a script](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/89566/196152). I mention this because Ruben's answer gives a step-by-step (fully detailed) example of how to implement that solution. The guidance offered by the answer might be what you need.

Comment: I notice @Rubén has continued to update his code for this; check the link to his gist - it's up to Vn5.

Comment: Will take a look at it. Thx

Comment: Referred to it once again,and there is no error from the trigger end. But still, the url did not update.

Answer (score 2):

The following points are taken from the latest version from @Rubén [latest version on github](https://gist.github.com/rubenrivera/4ed2110cda3fbdbc29d2d2d3a4af29c0). This code is a thing of beauty and a joy to behold. Combined with Rubén's detailed instructions, this answer can be setup and running in less than 5 minutes.

---

1. change
   `var formID = '__Your ID__';`
   to
   `var formURL = 'https://docs.google.com/forms/d/ -insert id - /edit';`
   you get the URL from the Forms Editor page.

---

2. change 
   `var columnName = 'Form URL';`
   to
   `var sheetName = 'URL'; // Column U`

---

3. replace `getEditResponseUrls` entirely

---

```
function getEditResponseUrls(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues(); 
  var columnIndex = headers[0].indexOf(columnName);
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var form = FormApp.openByUrl(formURL);
  for(var i = startRow-1; i < data.length; i++) {
    if(data[i][0] != '' && data[i][columnIndex] == '') {
      var timestamp = data[i][0];
      var formSubmitted = form.getResponses(timestamp);
      if(formSubmitted.length < 1) continue;
      var editResponseUrl = formSubmitted[0].getEditResponseUrl();
      sheet.getRange(i+1, columnIndex+1).setValue(editResponseUrl);
    }
  }
}
```

---

4. Remember to set the installable trigger.

Comment: Thx ted, could i trouble you to take a look at the script in the sheet. That is what i changed to but there was errors when running. Did i miss understand something you meant?

Comment: Open your form in the Google Forms editor - and copy the url. This is **NOT** the same as the viewform url (the one where you fill in the form); even the ID is different. Jut copy paste the url from the editor page into your code.

Comment: Just to confirm one SMALL thing. Once you have designed your form, while in the Forms editor you can click on the "cog" icon and adjust more settings. One of the settings is "Edit after submit", which, of course, should be ticked. Then "save" the settings, Then click "Preview", fill out the form, and you should get results on your spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

In the Google Sheet that you have linked from the question above, you have declared two functions with the same name and this could be a reason why the first one may never be executing. I tested this code and it seemed to work.

You may want to replace everything in the file with just this code.

```
var id = '1SdSPhOwi1dWQzRsNpA9zFL-ODorgohST3TMRJLqz16I';
var sheetName = 'Order Information';
var columnIndex = 21;

function getEditResponseUrls() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var form = FormApp.openById(id);
  for(var i = 2; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i][0] != '' && data[i][columnIndex-1] == '') {
      var timestamp = data[i][0];
      var formSubmitted = form.getResponses(timestamp);
      if (formSubmitted.length < 1) continue;
      var editResponseUrl = formSubmitted[0].getEditResponseUrl();
      sheet.getRange(i+1, columnIndex).setValue(editResponseUrl);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thx for your reply.I tested and there was no error,but no link was generated. Will keeping testing and trying out this and others in the mean time.

Comment: Try removing this condition `&& data[i][columnIndex-1] == ''`. It might be that there's data in the column.

Comment: I changed and tested. There is no error, but at the same time, there is no url being generated. Thx for trying.

Comment: What field do you have in Column A? The code's IF statement tests for this field `data[i][0] != '' ` so if you don't have any data in column A, then the code wouldn't work.