# Send Form response from prefilled link in Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I've tried to find some topic about it but without results
I would need only send Form from copied prefilled link in apps script but i am not able to find out where doing misstakes.

Here are two options what i've found but without good results.
Form doesn't send any response
I've replace in prefilled Link "viewform" for "formResponse" according to some instructions in web, but it does't work.
Do you can help me anyone?

```
function send() {

var config = {
    muteHttpExceptions: true,
    method: "get"
  };
var url = "https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/<form_id>/formResponse?usp=pp_url&entry.231322462=ANO&entry.133135319=1&entry.1743053173=2023-01-15"; 

var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, config);
//Logger.log(response)

}
```

or:

```
function send() {


var url = "https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/<form_id>/formResponse?usp=pp_url&entry.231322462=ANO&entry.133135319=1&entry.1743053173=2023-01-15"; 

var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
//Logger.log(response)

}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome. Would you please describe your scenario and the EXACT purpose of this script, and what response is obtained when the script(s) are run.

Comment: Related question: [How can I get the responses directly form a Google Form and send then to a new spreadsheet?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69564676/1330560) Since your script does NOT work, why not try one that DOES work.

Comment: All text - Hi, thx for reaction and formated my example of script. So, I have google sheet where i cutted whole prefilled link to questions and then fill up all answers for question in Form automatic by formulas. Than i create prefilled link again with new datas. And i would like send this link As response direct to Form responses without I have to enter to the form and click to send in form in Apps script. I am able to create and send standard response with script but I cannot found simple solution, how send response with use this link

Comment: Clarify: you want to write a script to edit existing Form Responses **in** the Form. At present, this isn't possible. [Edit Form Responses as soon as it is submitted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36638318/1330560). Lapky replied: "Hi, I don't mean it like that. Sorry for my bad explanation. Standart proces without Apps script - if i click on prefilled link, Form will be open with all prefilled answears, than i have to check whole Form and click on send Form - by hand. This proces i would like to write to Script, without need to open Form and click on send Form - by hand."

Comment: There are LOTS of precedents for this. Refer [How do i get the URL of a editable form response in spreadsheets](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57174263/1330560). This contains two solutions. One is based on some work by @Rubén and the other is by Amit Agarwal. Amit also runs [Digital Inspiration](labnol.org) and he has a page devoted to this [Add the Edit Response URL of Google Forms in Google Sheets](https://www.labnol.org/code/20540-edit-form-response-spreadsheet-url).

Answer (score 0):

You have an existing Google Form and you want to write a script in order to edit existing Form Responses **in** in the Form.

At the time of writing, this isn't possible.

Refer:

- [Edit Form Responses as soon as it is submitted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36638318/1330560)

Comment: Hi, I don't mean it like that. Sorry for my bad explanation. Standart proces without Apps script - if i click  on prefilled link, Form will be open with all prefilled answears, than i have to check whole Form and click on send Form - by hand. This proces i would like to write to Script, without need to open Form and click on send Form - by hand.